# Calculating Volume using a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm relatively new to Javascript and for one of my assignments at school I was asked to calculate the volume of a rectangular prism using 3 input boxes and a 4th one to display the volume. I made a function and defined my variables and gave each input box an id, when I input the numbers and run it through the function I made I keep getting NaN. What exactly is triggering this?

```
    <!doctype html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Surface Area &amp; Volume</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <script>
    "use strict";
    var $ = function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    };

    var length = $("length");
    var width = $("width");
    var height = $("height");
    var amountVolume = 0;
    function calculateVolume(length, width, height) {
        amountVolume = parseFloat(length) * parseFloat(width) * 
    parseFloat(height);
    var volumeRound = amountVolume.toFixed(2);
        $('volume').value = volumeRound;
    };


    </script>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <form>
    <h1>Surface Area & Volume</h1>

    <p>Length:

    <input type="text" id="length" value="0"/>

    </p>
    <br />
    <p>Width:

        <input type="text" id="width" value="0"/>

    </p>
    <br />
    <p>Height:

        <input type="text" id="height" value="0"/>

    </p>
    <br />
    <p class="change">Surface Area:

        <input type="text" id="area" disabled="disabled" />
    </p>
    <br />
    <p class="volume">Volume:

        <input type="text" id="volume" disabled="disabled" />
    </p>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="calculate" onClick="calculateVolume(length.value, width.value, height.value)" value="Calculate Volume"/>
   </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, your code is wrong, from where did you get this code? also, I can't seem to find you loading jQuery.

Comment: I set a variable as $ so I didn't have to type out document.getElementById whenever I wanted to call it

Comment: My bad didn't see that part, the problem is, in the `onClick` attribute you are not passing any values to the `calculateVolume()` function

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you don't need

```
 var length = $("length");
 var width = $("width");
 var height = $("height");
```

Beacause you are passing arrgument onClick="calculateVolume()"

And it is not working because you are using keyword as Id **height** and **width**,

Here is fully functional code

```
<!doctype html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Surface Area &amp; Volume</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <script>
    var $ = function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    };

    // var length = $("length");
    // var width = $("width");
    // var height = $("height");

    var amountVolume = 0;
    function calculateVolume(length, width, height) {

        console.log(length,width,height);
        amountVolume = parseFloat(length) * parseFloat(width) * 
    parseFloat(height);
    var volumeRound = amountVolume.toFixed(2);
        $('volume').value = volumeRound;
    };

    </script>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <form>
    <h1>Surface Area & Volume</h1>

    <p>Length:

    <input type="text" id="length" value="0"/>

    </p>
    <br />
    <p>Width:

        <input type="text" id="widthData" value="0"/>

    </p>
    <br />
    <p>Height:

        <input type="text" id="heightData" value="0"/>

    </p>
    <br />
    <p class="change">Surface Area:

        <input type="text" id="area" disabled="disabled" />
    </p>
    <br />
    <p class="volume">Volume:

        <input type="text" id="volume" disabled="disabled" />
    </p>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="calculate" onClick="calculateVolume(length.value, widthData.value, heightData.value)" value="Calculate Volume"/>
   </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you reference where does it says that you can't use `height` and `width` as they are reserved key words? i couldn't find them [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)

Comment: you update doesn't  answer the question why isn't it working with `width` and `height` as parameters

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the scope of `height` and `width` when executed in the context of the input's event handler.
Each `input` has a `width` and a `height` attribute, and when you try to pass the function the id - `width` and the id - `height` you are actually passing the `width` and `height` attributes of the button `input`, which none of them has a `value` key. That's why you get `undefined` for them.

If you want to reference the actual inputs width these id's you should reference them via the window object (All the elements id's are scoped to the window).

See the example below:

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

var length = $("length");
var width = $("width");
var height = $("height");
var amountVolume = 0;

function calculateVolume(length, width, height) {
  amountVolume = parseFloat(length) * parseFloat(width) *
    parseFloat(height);
  var volumeRound = amountVolume.toFixed(2);
  $('volume').value = volumeRound;
};
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <form>
    <h1>Surface Area & Volume</h1>

    <p>Length:

      <input type="text" id="length" value="0" />

    </p>
    <br />
    <p>Width:

      <input type="text" id="width" value="0" />

    </p>
    <br />
    <p>Height:

      <input type="text" id="height" value="0" />

    </p>
    <br />
    <p class="change">Surface Area:

      <input type="text" id="area" disabled="disabled" />
    </p>
    <br />
    <p class="volume">Volume:

      <input type="text" id="volume" disabled="disabled" />
    </p>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="calculate" onClick="calculateVolume(length.value, window.width.value, window.height.value)" value="Calculate Volume" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solutions

**Demo #1** uses the [HTMLFormElement Interface of the Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement). Note that the variables have been changed, the HTML has been modified with a semantic and functional layout that optimizes the use of form control fields. Instead of listening for a button click, **Demo 1** listens for the input event. Input event fires anytime there is data being entered.

**Demo #2** is a refactored version of OP's code.

The code you have cut and pasted is jQuery. jQuery is JavaScript but JavaScript isn't jQuery. Without going deep into a wide and expansive explanation of what jQuery is, I'll point out those discrepancies with a brief explanation that will probably need further research on your part.

---

The following list are mistakes found:

**1. The word `length`is a built-in JavaScript property**, when the browser sees it as a `var`, it's considered having a reassigned variable (i.e. undefined because Strings are immutable.)

---

**2. $() or jQuery()**

I assumed that you don't know what jQuery is when I saw this:

```
    var $ = function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    };
```

...I have no idea where to start on that one...it's a function expression that binds to on object with a given #id?

---

**3. REQUIRED:**

Place this in the `<head>` or before the `</body>` end tag:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

---

**4. jQuery/JavaScript Objects**

jQO (jQuery Object) are JavaScript Objects in a wrapper `$()`
JavaScript does not recognize jQuery, thus most methods that derive from the jQuery library, cannot be used with JavaScript Objects and vice versa. If you need a particular jQuery Object to be a JavaScript Object, then you need to dereference it:

**Method A:** *jQuery `.get()` method* - `var X = $('#xID').get(0);`

**Method B:** *Bracket Notatio*n - `var X = $('#xID')[0]`

---

**5.** `$("`**CSS SELECTOR**`")`

**Examples:**

`#`  - an element with an #id of `#width`: `$("#width")`

`.`  - element(s) with a class of `.height`: `$(".height")`

- element(s) by their tagName of `<a>`: `$("a")`

`[]`  - element(s) with an attribute of `type="text"`: `$("[type=text]")`

The first example applies to:

```
var length = $("length");
var width = $("width");
var height = $("height");
```

There are a couple of reasons why nothing worked:

- There are no such thing as `<length>`, `<width>`, or `<height>` elements.
- jQuery uses the CSS syntax for selectors so `var width = $("#width")` would be: `<input type='text' id='width' value='0' min='0'>`

**6. jQuery/JavaScript Functions/Methods/Properties**

The following concentrates on an issue particular to the OP's use of the property `.value`. There are 2 major ways to directly set/get the value of form controls:

**JavaScript**-----------------------------------------------------**jQuery**

```
                 <input id='IN' type="number">
                 <output id='OUT'></output>
```

`.value` property------------------------------------------ `.val()` method

---

`var dataIn = document.getElementById('IN').value;`----------------- `var dataIn = $('#IN').val();`

`document.getElementById('OUT').value = dataIn`---------------- `$('#OUT').val(dataIn)`

Given what we now know about `.value` property and `.val()` method, we now know that the error below can be fixed by replacing `.value` with `.val()`.

// Needs a # and .val()...

```
$('volume').value = volumeRound;
```

};

### Demo 1

```css
input,
output {
  font: inherit;
  width: 6ch;
}

label {
  display: block;
  width: 6ch;
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}

fieldset {
  float: right;
  transform: translateY(-175px);
  margin-right: 25px;
  width: 12ch
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Surface Area &amp; Volume</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <main id="main">
    <form id='AV'>

      <h1>Surface Area &amp; Volume</h1>

      <label>Length:
        <input type="number" id="L" min="0" oninput='A.value = Number(L.value)*Number(W.value)'>
      </label>

      <label>Width:
       <input type="number" id="W" min="0" oninput='A.value = Number(L.value)*Number(W.value)'>
      </label>

      <label>Height:
        <input type="number" id="H" min='0'  oninput='V.value = Number(A.value)*Number(H.value)'>
      </label>

      <fieldset>
        <label>Surface Area:
        <output id="A" for='W L'></output>
     </label>

        <label>Volume:
        <output id="V" for='A W L H'></output>
      </label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

### Demo 2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Surface Area & Volume</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 400 15px/1 Consolas;
    }
    
    .as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper {
      transform: translate(50vw, 50px);
      max-width: 250px;
      height: 100%;
      color: blue;
      font: inherit;
    }
    
    input,
    output {
      font: inherit;
      display: table-cell;
      width: 6ch;
    }
    
    label {
      font: inherit;
      display: table;
      width: 16ch;
    }
    
    #GO {
      width: 10ch;
      float: right;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Surface Area &amp; Volume</legend>
      <label>Width&nbsp;:
        <input type="number" id="X" value="0" min='0'>
      </label>
      <label>Length:
        <input type="number" id="Y" value="0" min='0'>
      </label>
      <label>Height:
        <input type="number" id="Z" value="0" min='0'>
      </label>
      <hr>
      <label>Area&nbsp;&nbsp;:
        <output id="D2"></output>
      </label>
      <label>Volume:
        <output id="D3"></output>
      </label>
      <input type="button" id="GO" value="Process">
    </fieldset>
  </form>


  <!-- Results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
  <script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    $('#GO').on('click', function() {
      var X = parseFloat($("#Y").val());
      console.log('Width = ' + X);
      var Y = parseFloat($("#Y").val());
      console.log('Length = ' + Y);
      var Z = parseFloat($("#Z").val());
      console.log('Height = ' + Z);

      var area = X * Y;
      console.log('Area = ' + area);
      var volume = area * Z;
      console.log('Volume = ' + volume);

      $('#D3').val(volume);
      $('#D2')[0].value = area;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```